# PC takes one hour to start from pressing power-on

Tags: boot, power-supply

When I press the Power-on button on my PC, it takes 1 hour before it starts.  If we wait for one hour or so then lights will glow and booting starts, and then everything is normal. Once the computer starts, if we shutdown and restart it starts immediately.

This behavior happens in the morning when we start the PC for the first time.   We replaced the power supply but thje problem still occurs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything on the screen during the hour you have to wait?  Does the screen light up when the PC is turned on?

Comment: @Paul nothing even  CPU LEDlights are also not blink it happens at morning only

Comment: Has it always been an hour, or has the length of time increased - is it sometimes less and sometimes more?

Comment: @Paul , not exactly an hour it usually a long time like 30 mins to  1hr or even more ..

Comment: capacitors failing to charge on the motherboard ?

Comment: In addition , if you haven't already, replace the standard HDD with a SSD.  I prefer the samsung evo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved itself when we changed the battery in the motherboard.

After observing the problem we found that every time the system started up after a long time, date and time settings were gone and the system would show `00-00-2000` as default date.

Comment: really ? interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to just guess-- motherboard issue? Have you tried swapping out the motherboard?

Comment: Take a look at the motherboard, are there any busted capacitors (http://www.cidrick.org/capacitors.jpg)

Comment: @nicholas , i will try change motherboard , let's see how it make difference .

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace the power supply.  It is the only component which is involved before power is on.

Comment: i already mentioned in my Q is that i already replaced Power supply but problem persisting

Comment: @panindra: At the time of writing, the question said "We replace SMPS", which was a bit opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Check up if the fan in the power supply revolves easily.
Try to check up the BIOS battery - the voltage must noticeably exceed 3V.
Unplug the outputs of the supply from everywhere, plug power cable and try to start the supply by connecting green and black wires that are in the largest plug.

Was the power supply you used for replace new? We have got just the same problem that was removed by another NEW power supply. Before that we sometimes did start the PC at once by first pressing the bower ON button and then -supplying the power by the power switch.